# How to change/modify the default location of OpenCart Theme Files?

Tags: opencart, web-deployment

How to change/modify the default location of OpenCart Theme Files?

How to exacly do this? let's say, one would want to put his theme files in the root folder, and the theme should work, wherever OpenCart is installed in a Domain. Wether installed in a sub-domoin, root or sub-folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying `DIR_TEMPLATE` constant in config.php and share your findings with us.